# Move from DataAnnotations to Fluent Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, fluentvalidation

Now I use validation based on custom DataAnnotation attributes and `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider`. Is fluent validation more fluent? :) Can it replace the DataAnnotations completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sad answer is no. There are several validation rules in DataAnnotations that are currently not inforced in FluentValidation. That said, server-side implementing the same validations is a somewhat easy task, but having to implement them client side as well is a pain.

I know they are - and have been - working on a new version of FluentValidation that should be out soon, that adds support for more validations including custom ones (client side)

Comment: What are these rules your are talking about (that can't be replaced by DataAnnotations)?

Comment: I think you ment, what rules that can't be replaced by FluentValidation? First off, with DataAnnotations you can write custom attributes that works both server-side and client side, that is currently not supported by FluentValidation. I also think that Regex and compare validators doesn't work client-side (unobtrusive atleast) with FluentValidation